# Is /etc/network/interfaces still working with newer Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan

I know newer Ubuntu are using Netplan to manage the network and it will replace the traditional `/etc/network/interfaces` way of network configuration.

I have to configure some Ubuntu machines this week and I wanted to know if my old `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration files in these new Ubuntu machines will work. I mean: if I configure the `/etc/network/interfaces` file properly... will it work properly or is Ubuntu going to ignore it because it is prepared to use Netplan?

Answer (score 3):

Netplan will replace the old /etc/network/interfaces, that means this file will not used anymore by default. But you can still use this file if required by installing the package ifupdown.

```
apt install ifupdown
```

This package is the service responsible to configure the network interfaces from /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Ok @olivierb2, so if I install ifupdown and configure the /etc/network/interfaces file, everything is going to work as I configure (static IP, etc.), isn't it?

Comment: Exactly, everything will work as previously !!